# Doctrine2 doesn't load Collection until a method is called

Tags: collections, doctrine-orm, load, lazy-evaluation, arraycollection

When does Doctrine2 loads the ArrayCollection?
Until I call a method, like count or getValues, I have no data
Here is my case. I have a Delegation entity with OneToMany (bidirectional) relation to a Promotion Entity, like this:

Promotion.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Promotion
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Delegation", inversedBy="promotions", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="delegation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $delegation;
}
```

Delegation.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Delegation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Promotion", mappedBy="delegation", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public $promotions;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->promotions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Now I do something like the following (with a given delegation)

```
$promotion = new Promotion();
$promotion = new Promotion();
$promotion->setDelegation($delegation);
$delegation->addPromotion($promotion);

$em->persist($promotion);
$em->flush();
```

Looking for the relation into the database is ok. I have my promotion row with the delegation_id set correctly.
And now my problem comes: if I ask for $delegation->getPromotions() I get an empty PersistenCollection, but if I ask for a method of the collection, like $delegation->getPromotions()->count(), everything is ok from here. I get the number correctly. Asking now for $delegation->getPromotions() after that I get the PersistenCollection correctly as well.
Why is this happening? When does Doctrine2 loads the Collection?

Example:

```
$delegation = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Delegation')->findOneById(1);
var_dump($delegation->getPromotions()); //empty
var_dump($delegation->getPromotions()->count()); //1
var_dump($delegation->getPromotions()); //collection with 1 promotion
```

I could ask directly for promotions->getValues(), and get it ok, but I'd like to know what is happening and how to fix it.

As [flu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601386/flu) explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261565/doctrine2-onetomany-manytoone-returns-empty-collection-with-database-ok/14261965#comment19820321_14261965) Doctrine2 uses Proxy classes for lazy loading almost everywhere. But acessing $delegation->getPromotions() should automatically invoke the corresponding fetch.
 A var_dump get an empty collection, but using it- in a foreach statement, for example- it is working ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `$delegation->getPromotions()` only retrieves the un-initialized `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` object. That object is not part of the proxy (if the loaded entity is a proxy).

Please refer to the API of [`Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php) to see how this works.

Basically, the collection itself is again a proxy (value holder in this case) of a real wrapped `ArrayCollection` that remains empty until any method on the `PersistentCollection` is called. Also, the ORM tries to optimize cases where your collection is marked as `EXTRA_LAZY` so that it is not loaded even when you apply some particular operations to it (like removing or adding an item).